# Service.onUnbind() called even if there are active clients?

Tags: android, android-service

The point of the exercise is: keep the service alive, passing it from one activity to another.

1. Activity A calls bindService() on service S;
2. S.onBound() called;
3. A.serviceConnection.onServiceConnected() is called;
4. Activity A starts activity B;
5. Activity B calls bindService() on service S;
6. B.serviceConnection.onServiceConnected() is called;
   5a: from onServiceConnected() activity B calls A.finish();
7. Activity A is stopping, calling unbindService(S) from its onDestroy() method.

Expected behavior: Service S continues to exist happily until activity B calls unbindService()

Actual behavior:

1. S.onUnbind() is called;
2. S.onDestroy() is called;
3. B.serviceConnection.onServiceDisconnected() is called;

thus destroying the link and contradicting the documentation.

Why? What am I missing?

Update: Solved. From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html:

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to **it with
>   the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag**.

Here's the code:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());

    private String serviceClassName;
    private ServiceConnection feedConnection;
    private Messenger feedMessenger;

    private void bind(String argument) {

        serviceClassName = TheService.class.getName();
        Intent intent = new Intent(serviceClassName);

        intent.putExtra(Keys.ACCOUNT, argument);

        feedConnection = new FeedConnection();

        if (!bindService(intent, feedConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to bind to " + argument);
        }

        logger.debug("bindService(" + serviceClassName + ") successful");
    }

    private void forward() {

        Intent intentB = new Intent();

        intentB.setClassName(B.class.getPackage().getName(), B.class.getName());
        intentB.putExtra(Keys.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME, serviceClassName);

        startActivity(intentB);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindService(feedConnection);
    }


    private class FeedConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            A.this.feedMessenger = new Messenger(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

            A.this.feedMessenger = null;
            logger.error("Crashed " + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()));
        }
    }
}

public class B extends Activity {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());
    private ServiceConnection feedConnection;
    private Messenger feedMessenger;
    private A activityA;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bindFeed();
    }

    private void bindFeed() {

        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

        String serviceClassName = startingIntent.getStringExtra(Keys.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME);

        Intent intent = new Intent(serviceClassName);

        feedConnection = new FeedConnection();
        // FIXME: BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag is missing
        if (!bindService(intent, feedConnection, 0)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to bind to " + serviceClassName);
        }

        logger.debug("bindService(" + serviceClassName + ") successful");
    }

    private class FeedConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            B.this.feedMessenger = new Messenger(service);

            logger.debug("bound " + className);

            // Finish the previous activity only after the service is bound            
            activityA.fileList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

            B.this.feedMessenger = null;
            logger.error("Crashed " + className);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: some code might be helpful here

Comment: Show us the code in `B.serviceConnection.onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: @derekerdmann - thanks for the hint, will mark in 2 days when the system allows me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Solved. From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html:

A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag.

Not quite intuitive in case when different connections are in asymmetrical roles, but alas, that's what it is.